# how to set fixed height based on sibling element's height

Tags: css, angular

Let's say I've two sibling elements A and B. I want to set B's height fixed to (container's height - A's height). So, child elements of B won't increase the height of B.

I've tried using Height: 100%;, but it is taking container's height, not (container's height - A's height)

Sample angular app:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivopeh

B's height should be fixed to (container's height - A's height) = (50px -30px) = 20px. So, if child element of B has height more then 20px, it should restrict its height to 20px and add scrollbar to it

Comment: Tip, not answer: you can solve it with display flex. (see [this nice article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

Comment: Try giving `html, body { height: 100% }`

Comment: does element A have a fixed height?

Comment: @EliasSoares I can't use display flex as i need to change complete layout

Comment: @nitin9nair this is just sample code, my code is very big and old. I don't think so html, body { height: 100% } will help in my scenario

Comment: @ysf yes, i can make A's height fixed

Answer (score 0):

I Would place this as a comment if I could.

To add a scrollbar to section b if the children are bigger than 20px you could `overflow-y:scroll` on section b(more documentation on overflow below). this way you only have to take care of the height which could be solved by adding flexbox or fixed values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

if A has a fixed height then changing class B as follows should do it;

```css
.B {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 20px /* A's fixed height. can be percentage, pixel, em, rem etc. */);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

`display: block;` is required for any `height` value set on B to be effective.

`overflow-y: auto` is required to display scroll bars in case B's content overflows.

here is a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mw3ugb